# Can a set of images be closed under intersection?

Tags: number-theory, functions

Let $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ and $g\colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be two linear functions.  Does there exist a function $h\colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$, not necessarily linear, such that $h(\mathbb{Z}) = f(\mathbb{Z})\cap g(\mathbb{Z})$?

How about the intersection of the images of $N$ linear functions?

Comment: Use the fact that the image of $f$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, and thus is the set of all multiples of a nonnegative $m\in\Bbb Z$, conventionally written $m\Bbb Z$. What, precisely, is $m\Bbb Z\cap n\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Surely there's a simple answer: for $u \in f(\Bbb Z) \cap g(\Bbb Z)$, define $h(u) = u$; for $u$ not in that set, define $h(u) = f(0) = g(0)$. Not as pretty as the answer that @Lubin's hinting at, though...  Exercise for Spencer: Where in this solution did I use linearity?Exercise 2: How could you modify this answer if the codomain was, say, $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Okay, $\mbox{lcm}(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, it’s the lcm.

Comment: Okay, now I see where I went wrong.  I was really interested in the question where $f$ and $g$ were not necessarily both linear.  This gives us a more interesting question.  The motivation is the prime number sieve.  Let $f(x)=1+2x$, $g(x)=1+3x$ and $h(x)=2+3x$.  Is there a function $j:Z\to Z$ such that $j(Z)=f(Z)\cap(g(Z)\cup h(Z))$?

Comment: That's a separate question, and should be asked as one, but my prior answer stands. As long as the intersection is *nonempty*, there is such a function. (If the intersection's empty, there's no place to send "all the other values", the way I used $f(0)$ in my comment above). But what you're probably hoping for is a generic way to construct not just a function, but a *formula* as well. That is, unfortunately, not a very well-specified problem, so I don't have a useful answer.